# Allow descendant to call overridden protected function on instance of another descendant

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, protected

Suppose we have a base class `Base` with a public interface, and some protected methods that are used to support the public interface. Simplified example:

```cpp
class Base {
    protected:
    virtual int helper() const = 0;
    
    public:
    virtual void do_work() {
        //By default, just call the helper. Descendants can customize behaviour.
        int x = helper();
        do_something_with_an_int(x);
    }
};
```

And suppose we have some descendants `DerivedA`, `DerivedB`, `DerivedC` ... that implement this interface.

The reason I want to split up the work in two functions (rather than just use `do_work` to do everything) is because I want to have a special descendant that might look something like this:

```
class DescendantWrapper : Base {
    Base *impl;
    int x;
    
    protected:
    int helper() const override {
        x += impl->helper();
    }
    
    public:
    void do_work() override {
        helper();

        if(some_internal_condition()) {
            do_some_other_thing_with_an_int(x);
        } else {
            x = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

The intention is to allow `DescendantWrapper` to wrap any descendant of `Base`, and take the place of that descendant in some other code. Of course, the other code would not be aware that its descendant of `Base` has been wrapped.

The problem is that a derived class (in this example, `DescendantWrapper`) cannot call a protected method on an *instance* of its parent class (in this example, `Base::helper()`).

One solution is to specifically declare `DescendantWrapper` as a friend of `Base`. However, this means that other users of this code couldn't create their own descendant wrappers. Does anyone know an alternative to friend functions in this scenario?

Comment: Not an alternative to friend, but you could create a class `DescendentWrapperBase` that provides a protected `helper` function with the logic shown in your `DescendantWrapper` class.

Comment: Oh, and would you have to mark `DescendantWrapperBase` as a friend of `Base`?

Quick proof-of-concept: https://godbolt.org/z/nxvjb3

Comment: Yes, indeed there should be a friend relationship between `Base` and `DescendantWrapperBase`. Forgot to mention that in the comment.

Comment: I like that solution. If you decide to write it as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.